# App Approval by Apple

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does apple view the actual source code when approving apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186648/does-apple-view-the-actual-source-code-when-approving-apps)

So I'm gearing up for my first submission to the App Store, but before I submit I have a quick question or two.

1) First off - when submitting, will Apple be looking through code and verifying its correctness or just testing the App itself?

2) If Apple is indeed looking closely at the code, does whether or not you follow Apple's suggested paradigms influence whether or not the App is accepted? For example; In my program I frequently use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated::]` rather than the Apple specified way of using delegation to have the presenting VC dismiss its presented VC's.

Just like to get feedback from people who maybe have already gone through the process and could give feedback on the experience. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You don't submit your source code to Apple, you submit a compiled binary - they can do static analysis to check for use of private APIs, etc, but they can't enforce a coding style or best practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple will not look at your code. All you submit is your binary application.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to submit the source code so be patient, none will stole your cool patterns :)

However, there's usually a good reason to recommend one or another approach, you'd better to think about following Apple recommendation not to appear among a lot of deprecated, slow or even disabled functionality.

Another point is that while they are not looking through your code directly, they are still kinda able to catch the used methods symbols which allows them to detect the private API usage and sometimes the app gets rejected just for your method being the match to the private API method from a signature, that's not happen often, but you better be accurate.

Another free recommendation for you - store the .dsym file somewhere, it will help you to symbolicate the crashes which could appear later right from the report file (you'll also need the app binary for that).

Comment: Thanks for the advice - very helpful. Wish I could accept 2 answers!